# Angular 4 Material Dialog Smooth Transition

Tags: angular, animation, angular-material2

Is there any way make the height and width of the material dialog transition from one size to another based on the content inside?

I have tried to add animation to the content inside, there is a smooth transition of the content, but the modal is still not transitioning properly. I want to modal to change width/height based on the content smoothly.

What I want: Height/Width of Modal Dialog to be smooth based on the content inside. e.g when the content is large and I switch to smaller content, I want the dialog to transition smoothly to the new size.

I used the updateSize() to update the size of the dialog but still, there is no transition.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similiar problem and found that the material dialog API can take a custom css class with the setting called panelClass. We can then define the transition using that custom css class.

```
// ts
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
  width: "45vw",
  height: "42vh",
  maxWidth: "100vw",
  maxHeight: "100vh",
  panelClass: "mat-dialog-height-transition"
});

// css class
.mat-dialog-height-transition {
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

Now when you update the dialog height inside your component, the dialog will resize with transition

```
export class MyDialogComponent {
...
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>) {}
...
someStateChanged(isEnlargeDialog: boolean) {
  this.dialogRef.updateSize("45vw", isEnlargeDialog ? "80vh" : "42vh");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `mat-tab-group` inside of the `MaterialDialog`. Switching from one tab to the other will have a very annoying jump in height if the two tabs are of different heights.

The closest I could get to avoiding the annoyance of those sudden jumps was to just prevent the Dialog from resizing itself. If you give an explicit height to the element serving as `mat-dialog-content`, it will keep that height always, whether the content will fit perfectly or not. It has to be an explicit size though, so nothing like `auto` or `100%`.

By default, the `max-height` for the `mat-dialog-content` is set to `65vh`.

[image: style of the mat dialog content element]

So you can set the `height` to `65vh` and the whole dialog should no longer shrink or grow.

Something like this. (Or by using a class and an external CSS).

```
<div mat-dialog-content style="height: 65vh"></div>
```

I'm hoping something can be done to allow smooth height transitions. Adding a `transition` property to the CSS doesn't help because the height is not explicit, it's rather taken from whatever the necessary height of the contained `div` is, so it jumps from one size to another.

Comment: `mat-tab-group` elements can have a `dynamicHeight` attribute which allows for smooth height adjustments. But the width change will not be animated though.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there's currently no such feature for custom dialog open/close animations.

There's an issue for custom dialog opening/closing animations, though. See [issue 8857](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8857) for more info.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I don't have any issues with closing and opening of dialogs. My dialog remains the same, only the content inside changes. I want the dialog to change to the small height or width with a transition and doesn't snap directly.